# Plot a line that intersects with the xy axes in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, line, points

I need a straight line which passes through these 2 points:

0.887, 0.000040318
0.1704, 0.001704

and be long enough to intersect with x-axis and y-axis. How could I do that on gnuplot? I've tried with a vector using first point and delta of both, but it wasn't long enough to intersect with y-axis.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Two points define a line.
Solve for the equation of that line in standard form as y = Ax + B

Choose a range on x and plot:

```
set xrange [ min : max ]
plot A*x + B with line
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the line defined by these two points. You can calculate it, you can do `fit` or if you want to use it several time, you can define a function for it:

```
f(x,x1,x2,y1,y2)=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2)*x+(x1*y2-x2*y1)/(x1-x2)
```

then

```
plot[0:] '-', f(x,0.887,0.1704,0.000040318,0.001704)
```

(and enter the coordinates of your points).